# The email must be a valid email address using laravel 6 and validate system

Tags: laravel, validation

I tried to use the validation system uses laravel 6, but even I created the correct format email (admin@admin.com) it gives me error message `The email must be a valid email address`.

```
'email' => ['bail','required', 'string', 'email:rfc,dns', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
```

sometimes it works but other time it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying a column name for your unique rule?

`'unique:users,{name of the email column here}'`

[From the Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique):

> The column option may be used to specify the field's corresponding database column. If the column option is not specified, the field name will be used.

I don't know if email is the correct name of your column or not, sometimes it doesn't hurt to be explicit with Laravel.

Comment: thx for u answer but it accept email like najibmarzouk@gmail even i dont add .com

Answer (score 0):

the email you provided (admin@admin.com), is not passing the rfc,dns validation check. To allow simple email validation, use this instead:

```
'email' => ['bail','required', 'string', 'email:dns', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
```

Comment: thx for u answer but it accept email like najibmarzouk@gmail even i dont add .com

Comment: yes, laravel is accepting that email because it is technically a valid email address even without the '.com'.
Notice that if you tell the browser to validate the email address, it will also pass.

Comment: yes, but if your application tries to send emails to such an email it will fail. So try and put back the dns option in the validator. I will update the answer to refelect that.